# How to change a div's outline color when selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the outline color when the div is selected. I have tried by using the same technique as hover (shown below), but I need help with a selector. Is it possible via JavaScript or is CSS enough?

Here is what I tried:

```css
div {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
}
div:hover {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: Why? What UI context does a "selected `div`" have?

Comment: If I am having text box inside div. how can I use this? <div tabindex="-1"><input class="text-input tab-text-input-mod" id="other-input" value=""></div>

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can try `:focus` pseudo-class. Note you will need [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) to make your `div`s focusable.

```css
div {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
}
div:focus {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1">1</div>
<div tabindex="-1">2</div>
<div tabindex="-1">3</div>
```

Comment: If I am having text box inside div. how can I use this?                                                                   <div tabindex="-1"><input class="text-input tab-text-input-mod" id="other-input" value=""></div>

Comment: @DineshKumar True. Since there can only be one focused element in the document, and `input`s are focusable, it won't work.

Comment: So how can I achieve this for textbox? Any idea?

Comment: Selectors L4 may introduce [`:focus-within`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-focus-within-pseudo).That would solve the problem, but there is no browser support yet.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using CSS:

```css
input:active,
input:focus,
textarea:active,
textarea:focus,
select:active,
select:focus {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using events?

```js
function selected(pDiv) {
    $("#div" + pDiv).attr("style", "border-style: solid");
    // Here write a For Loop to put "border-style: none" to everyone else
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" onclick="selected(1)">1</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="selected(2)">2</div>
<div id="div3" onclick="selected(3)">3</div>
```

Let me know if it worked...

Comment: A bit late response (some years ahead). Strange that nobody commented on your solution. Actually that was a very spot on technique. It worked for me.  Tested in all major browsers to date.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use `focus` instead of `hover`. The `:focus` selector is used to select the element that has focus. It is allowed on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs.

The difference between the two elements is that the `hover` event listens for the position of the mouse in relation to the web page, while the `focus` event listens for the selected item in the page.

So your code could look something like this:

```css
div {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
}
div:focus {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1">1</div>
<div tabindex="-1">2</div>
<div tabindex="-1">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26531702/1529630), you can use `:focus` pseudo-class.

But there is a problem: it won't work if the elements contain other focusable elements.

However, it can be fixed using JS events:

```js
var els = document.body.children;
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i) {
    els[i].addEventListener('focus', focus, true);
    els[i].addEventListener('blur', blur, true);
}
function focus() {
    this.classList.add('focus');
}
function blur() {
    this.classList.remove('focus');
}
```

```css
div {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
}
div:focus, div.focus { /* :focus is a fallback in case JS is disabled */
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1">
    1
    <input />
</div>
<div tabindex="-1">2</div>
<div tabindex="-1">3</div>
```

Note that in the code above I used capture phase because `focus` and `blur` don't bubble.

Alternatively, `focusin` and `focusout` could be used instead, but be aware Firefox doesn't support them yet (but they will work if you use jQuery).

```js
$('body > div').on('focusin', function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
}).on('focusout', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
```

```css
div {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
}
div:focus, div.focus { /* :focus is a fallback in case JS is disabled */
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div tabindex="-1">
    1 <input />
</div>
<div tabindex="-1">2</div>
<div tabindex="-1">3</div>
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to validate when div was focused or not?

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
 Fix select next previuos selected
 Fix duplicate clicks diselect
*/
var valuesOld = new Array();
var num = 0;

function selected(pDiv) {
    num = num +1;
    valuesOld[num] = pDiv;
    console.log("Key"+num+"Value="+valuesOld[num]);

    $("#div" + pDiv).css("border-left", " 1px solid rgb(133, 189,147)");

    if(valuesOld[2] > 0 && valuesOld[1]> 0){
        $("#div" + valuesOld[num-1]).css("border-left", " 1px solid rgb(221, 84, 84)");
    }
        if(pDiv == valuesOld[num]){
        $("#div" + pDiv).css("border-left", " 5px solid rgb(133, 189, 147)");
    }
}
```

```css
div{
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(221, 84, 84);
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div onclick="selected(1)" id="div1">1</div>
<div onclick="selected(2)" id="div2">2</div>
<div onclick="selected(3)" id="div3">3</div>
```